# Multisite sites output on a single page

Tags: multisite

Basically I have a multisite setup where each site is just one single page (each has a different theme). How can I output that page content of any site on a page of the main site programmatically?

Like I have multisite on domain.com and I have sites like `a.domain.com` and `b.domain.com`, then how can I show the content on lets say `domain.com/api/main` programmatically?

I need clues on how can I go about it? Output buffering in some way? Mainly I only need the widgets to work. Don't need the `is_*` functions as its just one page site.

Its like I want to view the content of diff sites on a single page by passing on parameters upon checking of which it is figured out which site of the multisite needs to be shown at this request & then that site is shown as if it was opened by its URL. Right now upon receiving the request on `domain.com/api/main`, I am redirecting to the site URL (`a.domain.com` or `b.domain.com`) but I would like to render the output on a single URL only. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I did this for a while on my own Multisite network.  Essentially, I had one site that was a central "hub" for all the others and pulled in content from the entire network.

It's not easy, but it can be done.  One approach (the approach I used at the time) used a plugin to automatically re-post content from each site on the central "hub" site.  The plugin is called [Sitewide Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/) and was originally intended to enable network-wide content searching.

A couple of talented WordPress users put together an ebook that details how to use the plugin, how to configure your network, and how to create "Network Homepages" similar to what you're asking for.

You can buy the ebook [here](http://wpebooks.com/aggregating-global-content/).

*Note: This is not my ebook and not an affiliate link.  I used this ebook while setting up my own network "hub" site, which is why I'm comfortable recommending it.*

Comment: Just to make sure you have not misunderstood me. Instead of just pulling the content, I want to show it along with the theme, how exactly it will look when that particular site is opened `a.domain.com` Can I learn that from the mentioned resource?

Comment: It sounds more like you want to display the content in an iFrame.  This is the best way to keep the look/feel exactly the same.  But really, I don't think I understand how your network is set up or what you're trying to do.  It almost sounds like you have a network where each blog is a single page, and you're trying to programatically merge them into a single website ...

Comment: Its like I want to view the content of diff sites on a single page by passing on parameters upon checking of which it is figured out which site of the multisite needs to be shown at this request & then that site is shown as if it was opened by its URL. Did I do better in explaining?